# hostapd disconnect my clients when browsing (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, hostapd

I'm trying to make my own Wi-Fi network using a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B (connected on Ethernet) and `hostapd` version 2.8-devel.

My config looks like that:

```
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
hw_mode=g
channel=4
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
ssid=Minteck-Projects
wpa_passphrase=mysupersecretpassphrase
country_code=FR
```

And the problem is that when I access a YouTube video on my phone, the Wi-Fi is disconnected. But if I don't access Internet (I tested by keeping on the **Wi-Fi Settings** page), the phone don't get disconncted.

Other info:

`uname -a`:

```
Linux ws-rpi-10666 4.19.75-v7+ #1270 SMP Tue Sep 24 18:45:11 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

`lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

`ifconfig`:

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.27  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::****:****:****:****  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a01:****:****:****:****:****:****:****  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether b8:27:**:**:**:**  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3172  bytes 447485 (436.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 105  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 822  bytes 112621 (109.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.27  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether b8:27:**:**:**:**  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4594  bytes 995920 (972.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1161  bytes 216045 (210.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 192  bytes 11701 (11.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 192  bytes 11701 (11.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.27  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether b8:27:**:**:**:**  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 322  bytes 87073 (85.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2585  bytes 760999 (743.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Any help will be useful, thanks!

Comment: Do you really need to use TKIP?

Comment: I don't know, I just copy-pasted the config from the official Raspberry Pi docs.

Comment: TKIP was deprecated a long time ago, is insecure and certain wifi devices in Linux don't like it. It's generally recommended to use WPA2-AES only.

Comment: I'll try that and let you know